# How can I calculate the length of groups of consecutive ones in binary vector?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a series of binary vectors (time x 1) in which 1s represent a connection between two variables at a given point in time. The connections between the two variables are sporadic, and I would like to know how 'long' each connection between the two variables exists for.

e.g. if the vector for a given set of variables is:

```
[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
```

Then I would like to create a new variable which contains the length of contiguous 1s in each instance. From the above example, the new variable would look like this:

```
[3,1,7]
```

As the first time that a 1 arose, it was there for 3 consecutive time points, whereas the next time it was only there for 1 time point and finally, the connection was in the data for 7 consecutive time points.

If there is a good way to solve this, I'd love some help.

Cheers

Mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diff` and `cumsum` give a good pair!

```
a = [0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ]
b = cumsum([a 0])
c = diff( [0 b(diff([a 0]) == -1) ] )
%// or
c = diff( [0 b(~(diff([a 0]) + 1)) ] )
```

---

```
c =

     3     1     7
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to put.  +1.